# TinyMCE doesn't load after putting a CDN on website

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

After I put the blog behind a CDN (CloudFront), TinyMCE no longer loads on the WP admin editor. Has anyone experienced this before? Everything else seems to be working fine. Glad to answer any questions that might help. I'm on WP 4.7.2. `window.tinymce` just doesn't exist, and the editor isn't showing a visual mode.

edit: I'm now forcing tinymce to load by adding the script to the head using a plugin, but the editor is still not loading it.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console related to loading the TinyMCE JS files?

Comment: @MichaelFromin there are not. I believe the files are simply not even being requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`, it checks to see if `user_can_richedit()` before serving the proper scripts. This function returns based on the browser the user has, which is told by the request headers. The request headers are overwritten by CloudFront, so my solution was to remove the `user_can_richedit()` condition.